# Why is Office required for multiple file uploading?

Tags: 2010, file-upload

Why is Office required for multiple file uploading?
I don't have Office, is there something I can install that will enable this feature?

Answer (score 6):

There is an ActiveX control that is used to support multiple file uploading - that ActiveX control is installed with office.

Comment: I don't have Office, is there something I can install that will enable this feature?

Answer (score 6):

@Kirk: Depending on your SharePoint version it should be sufficient to either install SharePoint Designer 2007 or 2010.

Edit: Forgot to mention that SharePoint Designer is a free download from the Microsoft Website.

Comment: Great workaround.

Comment: Do you have the link?

Comment: Microsoft SharePoint Designer 2010 (32-bit)  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=d88a1505-849b-4587-b854-a7054ee28d66

Comment: SharePoint Designer 2007 https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=baa3ad86-bfc1-4bd4-9812-d9e710d44f42 and don't forget to apply the latest Service Pack too https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=88EFF285-0B92-45ED-979B-65AA22304DD6

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this recent question '[What are the client side requirements to enable the “upload multiple files” link?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14116/what-are-the-client-side-requirements-to-enable-the-upload-multiple-files-link/14121#14121)'

You can also upload multiple files using WebDav (Explorer View). Office is not required for that. See [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/your-client-does-not-support-opening-this-list-with-windows-explorer/15106#15106) for requirements.